# Mean Value Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I am trying to formulate a proof of the mean value theorem.

I am given that $f'$ is strictly increasing.

So far I have said the following:

Let $$f(x)=g(x)-\lambda x \text{ with } \lambda \text{ such that } g(a)=g(b)$$

From here I can say that $$f(a)=g(a)-\lambda a \text{ and } f(b)=g(b)-\lambda b.$$

Then from this $$g(a)-g(b)=0 \Rightarrow f(a)-f(b)-\lambda (a-b)=0$$

And so $$\lambda = \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$

Then by Rolle's Theorem, there exists $c$ such that $g'(c)=0-f'(c)-\lambda \Rightarrow f'(c)=\lambda$

Thus we have that $$f'(c)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a.}$$

I know that this is correct, I need to show that there is only one $c$ for which this is true though. I assume it has something to do with $f'$ being strictly increasing. How can I do this?

Comment: It's just an extension of the original question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use contradiction. [and the fact that derivatives have the intermediate value property.]

Comment: Could you elaborate on this please?

Comment: Actually, you don't need IVP. The possibility of another point where f' equals lambda contradicts the fact that f' is strictly increasing.

Comment: So if I start with something like 'Suppose there exist $c,c'$ such that $f(b)-f(a)=f'(c)(b-a)$. This implies that $f'(c)=f'(c')$ and so since $f$ is injective, $c=c'$. Is that right?

Comment: Check the case where c<c' and the one where c'<c. You should have f'(c)<f'(c') and f'(c')<f'(c) respectively. But that is a contradiction since in either case you have f'(c)=f'(c').

Answer (score 2):

You have:

$$f'(c)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$

$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$ can be evaluated. As $f'(c)$ is strictly increasing this means that it is a one-to-one function (which passes the horizontal line test), and hence there is only one value of $c$ which can satisfy:

$$f'(c)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$

Comment: How would one show that this is the case?

Comment: What is the case? If you're asking about the one-to-one function bit, this is about injectivity.

Comment: That there is only one value of $c$ that can satisfy the equation. As in how would you write a proof of this.

Comment: As $f'$ is strictly increasing, it is injective. Hence there is only one value of $c$ which satisfies the equation.

Comment: How does $f'$ being strictly increasing imply that $f$ is injective?

Comment: Because that is one of the methods of proving injectivity. If you draw a graph of $f'$ which is strictly increasing, it cannot go back down - it can only increase. Therefore, the graph passes the horizontal line test and is injective.